# Installing pandoc from backports on Debian stretch

Tags: debian, software-installation, backports, pandoc

I followed the instructions at https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

But when trying to get a newer version of `pandoc` with `apt-get -t stretch-backports install 'pandoc'`, I just get:

```
pandoc is already the newest version (1.17.2~dfsg-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
```

But I see there is a newer version on buster: https://packages.debian.org/buster/pandoc

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not.

Comment: I removed the package and tried reinstalling from `stretch-backports` but got same result. Still running old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

[Stetch-Backports](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch-backports&searchon=names&keywords=pandoc) does not have `pandoc`. The version of `pandoc` you are installing is coming from your main Stable (Stretch) repository. [Here is a list](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pandoc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) of all available versions of `pandoc` in the Debian Repos.

I would advise against just simply adding the Buster repos to your system to avoid creating [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). Buster is in the middle of a [full freeze](https://release.debian.org/buster/freeze_policy.html) and should be set to be released as the next Debian Stable in a few months.

Please consider what features that `pandoc 2.2.1` has that you feel you are missing in `pandoc 1.17.2`. Debian back ports security fixes so unless you are encountering a bug or are missing a new feature it may not be necessary to upgrade.

If you require the newer version of `pandoc` this leaves your options as:

- Waiting for Debian Buster to release and fully upgrading your system, getting the new package at that time.
- Upgrading to Buster now to get the package.
- Asking for a backported package to be uploaded (by filing a bug, `reportbug pandoc`).

However, these tasks are outside the scope of your current question.

Comment: I am seeing a bug not in pandoc but in a vim plugin related to pandoc: https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/255